# Tomcat7 keeps loading after restart

Tags: 14.04, tomcat7

**The problem:**

The Tomcat7 startup page keeps loading after restarting its service using either `/etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart` or `service tomcat7 restart`. I only tested using Ubuntu 14.04.2.

**How I encountered the problem (and maybe how it could be reproduced):**

1. `apt-get install tomcat7`
2. (check the default page using your browser, it should work)
3. `service tomcat7 restart`
4. Check default page and see that it keeps loading

**The question:**

Am I making a mistake? How can this problem be solved and why is it happening?

Comment: I suggest you also take look > /var/log/tomcat7/localhost_access_log > /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out you can > tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/localhost_access_log and reload the page to see if there is new entry

Comment: I do not have a localhost_access_log file. in the catalina.out file, there are a few errors but they are from when I was changing a few things (after posting the question).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem is occurring very often for my hosting service, **DigitalOcean**.

Because I didn't look for a DigitalOcean-related problem, I didn't see that the problem has been [resolved on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431922/tomcat7-starts-too-late-on-ubuntu-14-04-x64-digitalocean#answer-27250730).

From linked post:

> ```
> JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
> ```

Adding the line above in `/etc/default/tomcat7` and restarting the service resolved the problem.